# Different size folders using terminal commands (ubuntu) and folder properties

Tags: command-line, disk-usage

I want to get the size of a folder I'm working on and I've tried the following:

- right-click and check folder's properties (105.8MB)
- Commands directly in terminal insed the folder:

  - du -hsc * (last line where total
    appears 105MB)
  - du -sch (last line where total appears 418MB)

Why am I getting such different sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`du -hsc *` estimates the sizes of all the files in the current directory and renders the total of all of them, but excludes the hidden folders in the estimation.

`du -sch` estimates the sizes of all the files in the current directory and renders the total of all of them, and also includes the hidden folders in the estimation.

Comment: So when we check the size of a folder in its properties it's not adding the size of  hidden folders, right?

Comment: Yes. If you navigate to different directories, you will find that `du -sch` just returns the size of `.`, which is everything(including the hidden files), and `du -hsc *` just gives the same output as a right click.